# RazorPDF2 - The document has no pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando utilizar o [RazorPDF2](https://github.com/DesignLiquido/RazorPDF2) para gerar o PDF de uma *view*.
Coloco um *breakpoint* tanto no *controller* quanto na *view* e ambos estão executando sem erro algum, porém depois que termina a execução sempre retorna o erro:

> The document has no pages.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The document has no pages.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Segue meu controller:

```
public ActionResult Pdf(int? id)
{

    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Orcamentos Orcamentos = db.Orcamento.Find(id);

    var pdf = new PdfActionResult( Orcamentos);
    pdf.FileDownloadName = "Pdf";
    pdf.ViewName = "Pdf";

    return pdf;// View(Orcamentos);

}
```

Segue a View (deixei só o básico, mas mesmo assim não vai):

```
@model OrcamentosSeal.Models.Orcamentos

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Orcamento" + Model.Orcamento.CJ_NUM;
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Teste</p>   
</body>
</html>
```

---

Reinstalei o pacote via NugGet e usei o modelo [_PdfHtmlLayout.cshtml](https://github.com/DesignLiquido/RazorPDF2/blob/master/RazorPDFExample/Views/Shared/_PdfHtmlLayout.cshtml) e funcionou.

Comment: Acho que vou atualizar o pacote no NuGet pra você fazer mais um teste. `PdfActionResult` usa o método de outro pacote, e não do RazorPDF2. Se for o caso, vou te pedir pra colocar o projeto num repositório público pra eu fazer uns testes aqui.

Comment: Tentei utilizando o layout de exemplo [_PdfHtmlLayout.cshtml](https://github.com/DesignLiquido/RazorPDF2/blob/master/RazorPDFExample/Views/Shared/_PdfHtmlLayout.cshtml) e nada, entao reinstalei o pacote e tentei de novo sem fazer nenhuma alteração e foi. Agora esta rodando 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Se sua intenção é ver em tela, altere para isso:

```
 return new PdfActionResult("NomeDaView", Orcamentos));
```

Comment: Já havia testado tanto setando a propriedade **FileDownloadName** quanto retornando direto para visualizar na tela, sempre dava o mesmo erro.

Comment: @JuanSabino Mas em seu exemplo você não seta o `Layout` em sua `View`, onde está: `Layout = null;`

Comment: Criei o arquivo layout e especifiquei na minha view, mas continua do mesmo jeito. Se eu retorno com View(Orcamentos); ele exibe a página normal, com o layout ou sem.

Comment: @JuanSabino Tente passar o nome da `View` junto. Acabei de editar a resposta.